# What is better to use ImageView or Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, imageview

I'm developing a music app but I have a big question. I have two imageview, one is bigger the other and this one is the stroke of the cover of the album.

I have read that if I want to draw something that it doesn't go to change is better to use an imageview and in the case of paint something is going to change in a short period of time is better to use Canvas.

What do you recommend me? Use canvas for Cover? And how Can I make the stroke of the image? because nowadays I have a imageview with a drawable that never change but it is not correct. I tried to put a personal drawable to Imageview but when I insert or change the cover, automatically the stroke is under the image, so...

I hope you have understood me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GO with the `ImageView` with image source, u dont need canvas for your requirement

Comment: And for the border of the image, what do you recommend me? I use other Imageview as I told before. I make an imageview and over it, other imageview with the picture, I think it is a bit tight.